# Haskell: Evaluate any Ast into a string

Tags: haskell

I have an assigment where I have to program an evaluation function eval::Ast -> String which evaluates any Ast into a string. for example:

```
>eval (parse "hel + lo") 
"hello"

> eval (parse "mi + 2 * la")
"milala"
```

I've made a parse-function that e.g. takes "hel + lo" and returns Plus (Word "hel") (Word "lo")

But I am very unsure of what the function (and types) should look like as there are multiple types involved in the evaluation of the AST... Anyone who can put me in the right direction?

The AST is defined as

```
data Ast 
 = Word String
 | Num Int
 | Mult Ast Ast
 | Plus Ast Ast
 | Minus Ast Ast
 deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: The "rules given in the introduction" are unknown to most people. Does `2 + 3` evaluate to `"5"` or `"23"`? How about `"hello" - "world"` (I can imagine both `"hello"`,`"hel"`, and `"he"`)? `"hello" * "world"`? (It's not easy to come up with anything meaningful for that last one.)

Comment: Oh haha, I thought those rules weren't relevant to know for the task I'm having trouble with, so I didn't share them. But it's basically that  ```*``` has the highest precedence, while ```-```  and  ```+```  associate to the right. ```"cabbage - aabcd"``` should be evaluated to  ```"be"```  and  ```"3 * yes"```  should be evaluated to  ```"yesyesyes"```  etc. @molbdnilo

Comment: I think you need to have *two* evaluation functions; one to evaluate numerical sums and products when they occur as arguments along side a string, and one to evaluate numbers as strings for final output. Consider `mi + (1 + 1) * la`, which I assume parses to `Plus (Word "mi") (Mul (Plus (Num 1) (Num 1)) (Word "la"))`.

Comment: Your task is lterally to translate those rules into code, so they are far more relevant than your parser code.

Comment: You might also consider `eval :: AST -> Either String String`, as it's not clear that `"foo" * "bar"` can be evaluated, despite being grammatically correct.

Comment: Something like `Plus (Num 1) (Num 2)` should probably be *simplified* to `Plus (Num 3)` before attempting to evaluate it as a string. I'd write two functions, `simplify :: AST -> AST` and `eval :: AST -> Either String String`. `eval x = eval' (simplify x) where ...`, `eval'` being the function that does things like `eval' (Num x) = show x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval :: AST -> String` is what defines the semantics of your operations. For example, `eval (Plus (Word x) (Word y)) == x ++ y`.

However, what should `eval (Plus x y)` produce if both arguments are numbers? Should it concatenate them, or add them numerically? What if either one *itself* is one of the `Plus`, `Minus`, or `Mul` values? You would need to evaluate them first, but then you can't tell if a result like `"2"` is really a string, or the result of a number.

You also need to decide if every `AST` *can* be evaluated: does `Mul (Word "x") (Word "y")` make sense? If not, what `String` would you return?

I would suggest two things:

First, define a `simplify` function that takes care of reducing the `AST` to something simpler. It will take care of doing things like numerical arithmetic in the case of `Plus (Num ...) (Num ...)`, but leave things like `Word x` or `Plus (Word x) (Num y)` unchanged.

```
simplify :: AST -> AST
simplify (Num x) = Num x  -- Easy case done for you; no simplification necessary
simplify (Word x) = ...
-- Hint: in each of the following, you need to recursively simplify the operands.
-- Once you do that, you can either simplify further, or return a new
-- node to be evaluated.
simplify (Plus x y) = ...
simplify (Minus x y) = ...
simplify (Mul x y) = ...
```

Second, define `eval :: AST -> Either String String`, will first use `simplify` on its argument, *then* do case-by-case conversions of `AST`s to `Strings` where feasible, and returning an appropriate error message where it isn't.

```
eval :: AST -> Either String String
eval x = eval' (simplify x)
   where eval' (Word x) = Right x  -- Easy case done for you
         eval' (Num x) = ...
         -- simplify will have reduced all the Num + Num, Num - Num, and
         -- Num * Num nodes to single Num nodes already.
         eval' (Plus (Word x) (Word y)) = x ++ y  -- Other easy case done above
         eval' (Plus x y) = ...
         eval' (Minus (Word x) (Word y)) = ...
         eval' (Minus x y) = ...
         eval' (Mul (Word x) (Word y)) = ...
         eval' (Mul x y) = ...
```

Note that you could conceivably define some combinations in either `eval'` or `simplify`, e.g.

```
simplify (Plus (Word x) (Word y)) == Word $ x ++ y
```

leaving the more complicated (and possibly impossible) cases to `eval`.

Comment: Everything makes so much more sense now! Thank you very much, you are great

Comment: I put e.g ```simplify (Mult x y) = "(" ++ (show x) ++ "*" ++ (show y) ++ ")"``` , and i get the "Couldn't match expected type ‘Ast’ with actual type ‘[Char]’"- error. I've tried different ways of trying to simplify the operands, but I think I may have misunderstood something :S @chepner

Comment: `simplify` doesn't return a `String`; it returns an `AST` (possibly the same on you passed as an argument). For example, `simplify (Mult (Num 3) (Num 5)) == Num 15`. If you can't actually do the multiplication, you just return the node as-is and let `eval` try to do something with it. The idea is to not prematurely convert `Num 5` to `"5"`, only to find out you need to multiple another string by `5`. Now you don't know if the original input was `5 * "foo"` or `"5" * "foo"`.

Comment: Aha, ok! But what if I only want to evaluate strings, what should I put there then? I would give ```5 * 2``` an error, but let ```3*hi```evaluate to ```hihihi```

Comment: `simplify (Mul (Num 3) (Word "hi")) ==  (Mul (Num 3) (Word "hi"))`; you can pass this directly to `eval`.